# Hash dentro de outro Hash retorna sempre vazio se não for usado uma chave

Tags: ruby

Bom criei um método para agrupar todos os commits de um usuário por mês em um Hash:

```
def calculate_month_ranking(commits)
  rank = Hash.new(Hash.new(0))  
  commits.each do |commit_yml|
    commit = YAML.load commit_yml.data

    commit[:commits].each do |local_commit|      
      time = Time.parse(local_commit[:timestamp])
      month = "#{time.month}/#{time.year}"
      rank[month][commit[:user_name]]+= 1
      binding.pry # para debug
    end

  end

  rank  
end
```

O resultado é que ao recuperar os dados pelo mês os dados aparecem, mas a variável `rank` está vazia como podem ver no debug abaixo

```
[1] pry(main)> rank[month]
=> {"user1"=>4, "user2"=>1}
[2] pry(main)> rank
=> {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso você está alterando o fallback do seu hash para chaves que não existem (quando você faz: `rank = Hash.new(Hash.new(0))`).

Ou seja, sempre que você tentar acessar uma chave que não existe no `rank` você acaba acessando um novo hash (`Hash.new(0)`), e o problema é que esse novo hash é que está recebendo o valor da atribuição `rank[month][commit[:user_name]] += 1`, e o hash `rank` acaba não recendo essa atribuição internamente -- é meio complicado explicar isso, e para falar a verdade nem eu sei como isso funciona internamente XD.

Mas você pode checar todos os valores da seguinte maneira:

```
[1] pry(main)> rank.default
=> {"junho"=>{"user1"=>4, "user2"=>1}}
```

Leia mais na API:

> [Hashes have a default value that is returned when accessing keys that do not exist in the hash. If no default is set nil is used. You can set the default value by sending it as an argument to ::new:](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html)